# How to dynamically add .Where() clause in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a method:
Where I defined an expression, which will be in linq query only if input param `userType` has value.

```cs
public Institution GetInstitutionWithServices(int institutionId, UserTypes? userType)
{
  Expression<Func<Service, bool>> serviceUserTypeFilter = (s => true);

  if (userType.HasValue)
  {
    serviceUserTypeFilter = (s => s.UserType == userType.Value);
  };

  var query = _dbContext.Institution.Include(a => a.Services)
                                    .Where(a => a.Id == institutionId)
                                    .Select(m => new Institution
                                     {
                                       Id = m.Id,
                                       Name = m.Name
                                    .Where(x => x.Status == Service.ServiceStatus.Published) 
                                     //&& userType.HasValue ? x.UserType == userType.Value : false )
                                    .Where(serviceUserTypeFilter)
                                    .ToList()
                                    }).FirstOrDefault();
  return query;
}
```

I don't know how to add filter for other table (db context) which has foreign key.
It has Services.
In commented where part that I need to invoke thorugh expression, because I'm getting null reference exception with that code
The error with this code that I'm getting is:

> Error CS1503
>   Argument 2: cannot convert from '`System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<Test001.Domain.Service, bool>>`' to '`System.Func<Test001.Domain.Service, bool>`'
>   Test001.Repositories

Comment: As a side note, your `var query` should be named `var result` because it returns the result rather than the query itself.

Comment: ofcourse @GSerg..I will edit that. thanks

Comment: so I need wrapped in Expression for SQL..

Comment: I can't shake of the feeling that your query seems odd, your `Institution` class member `Name` is getting initialized with a `List`, is that correct? Talking tbout this line of code `Name = m.Name.Where(x => x.Status == Service.ServiceStatus.Published).Where(serviceUserTypeFilter).ToList()`

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing stopping you adding `.Where` clauses after the main query has been defined:

```
 var query = _dbContext.Institution.Include(a => a.Services);
 if(something)
 {
    query = query.Where(a => a.Id == institutionId);
 }

 ...
 var results = query.ToList();  // <-- This 'executes' the query

 etc
```

At any point up to when the query is actually executed (in your case .ToList()) you can keep adding other linq clauses (.Where, .OrderBy etc).

Comment: thanks @Neil, I didnt know that I can chain query like that :)

Comment: but I cant see my Select in my query

Answer (score 0):

It seems your code contains errors (what is the "..m.Name.Where(x => x.Status..."?), but i guess you need something like this solution:

```
Expression<Func<Service, bool>> servicesWhereClause;
        if (!userType.HasValue)
            servicesWhereClause = x => x.Status == Service.ServiceStatus.Published;
        else
            servicesWhereClause = x => x.Status == Service.ServiceStatus.Published
                && x.UserType == userType.Value;
        var result = _dbContext.Institution
            .Include(a => a.Services)
            .Where(a => a.Id == institutionId)
            .Select(i => new
            {
                Institution = i,
                Services = i.Services.Where(servicesWhereClause)
            })
            .ToList()
            .Select(anon => new Institution
            {
                Id = anon.Id,
                Name = anon.Name,
                // etc...
                Services = anon.Services
            })
            .ToList();
```

if you want to get filtrated child records with parent records at once you should use anonymous return type and do map after that. Unfortunately, ef will no track such records.

Comment: servicesWhereClause expects func not expression in brackets.. it doesnt work it throws an exception when I remove Expression wrapping: `Could not parse expression 'i.Services.Where(__servicesWhereClause_1)': The given arguments did not match the expected arguments: Object of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.TypedParameterExpression' cannot be converted to type 'System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression'.`